# Apache web server not starting

Tags: xampp

I have installed xampp on ubuntu. But can not start apache web server and it gives the following error. How can I stop or remove the server that currently running and start the apache web server?

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.21-0...  
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.  
XAMPP:  Another web server with SSL is already running.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Running the command `netstat -tulpn | grep ':80\|:443'` will display a list of processes running on ports 80 and 443. You can use that info to stop the processes, move them to another port or, alternatively, you could move your new XAMPP installation to a different port.